# How can I allow multiple users to update a parse object?

Tags: ios, swift, object, parse-platform, updating

I am building an iOS app that takes polls. I am using parse as the back end. One example poll would be a presidential candidates approval rating. The way I have this built is each presidential candidate has their own object, of which one property is "score". Right now users can add or reduce value to this score, and the value is updated on parse. That is done with this code:

```
let cQuery = PFQuery(className: "score")

                    cQuery.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(canidateIDArray[canidate]!) {
                        (object, error) -> Void in
                        if error != nil {
                            print(error)
                        } else {
                            if let object = object {
                                object["score"] = object["score"] as! Int + self.score
                            }
                            object!.saveInBackground()
                        }
```

What I am worried about is what would happen if two users updated the same score at about the same time. For example, the score for a candidate is 10, and a user updates that +2, but right after another user updates it + 3, the total score I want it to have is 15. But if the first users score isn't saved before the second user makes the request for the score, would the score just be saved as 13, or would parse account for the two requests?

Is there a better way to do this, by perhaps updating the score without requesting what it is first? Or is it possible for parse to combine multiple scores into one some how? I want the user to only have to retrieve one score for each candidate. Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Can't you create a new object each time a user adds a score and add up all the objects when you want to get the score?

Although this makes fetching a bit more difficult, you won't need to fetch the score => add score => submit score.

You'd only have to create a new score object. Also, it makes it easier to track how much an individual player has scored throughout the game.

Answer (score 1):

Parse won't know if you want to add or subtract the score. Imagine User 1 queries the object before User 2, but not after User 2 update the score - then they will both have 10 on the object. User 1 wants to add 3, and User 2 wants to add 2. User 1 will send a save request as 13, and User 2 will send another for 12. Whichever request is processed last will be the final score, and it won't be 15.

My suggesstion is that you create a CloudCode to put the addition and subtraction in a queue and process them, other than allow users to directly write the final value.

Or you can add a record for each addition and subtraction, but then the score will have to be calculate everytime with those record (you can also use CloudCode)